# Can't seem to get PHP appendChild to work correctly when importhing html node

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to append a node (with sub-nodes) from an imported snippet of html into the body an existing html DOM Document. I've been having a heck of a time trying to get the node to append in the correct place.

Here is my code:

```
$lastnode = $loaded_file->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->lastChild;
$newnode = $editor_doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->firstChild;
$newnode = $loaded_file->importNode($newnode, True);
$lastnode->appendChild($newnode);
```

`$loaded_file` is a html file loaded as a DOMDocument using loadHTML. 
`$editor_doc` is the html snippet also loaded as a DOMDocument using loadHTML

The output is the following:

```
[Entire document of $loaded_file ending with </html>]
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>1974
[the correct html snippet]
</p></body></html>
```

2 problems:
1) The snippet is in the wrong place. I thought it was appending it as a child of the body tag, am I doing something wrong?
2) I have no idea where the extra !DOCTYPE, html, body p and 1974 text are coming from. There is nothing in my code that adds that. Seems to show up when i use appendChild on anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Apparently instead of using `loadHTML(readfile($filename))` you have to use `loadHTMLfile($filename))` while it seems that everything was loading correctly apparently it wasn't, and i'm not sure why. But once I changed that everything seemed to work correctly.